# Can't figure out who is calling a class

Tags: objective-c, ios

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PeopleData initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6888c10'`

I'll try to make it simple. How does this line:

```
NSData* objData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:[newStorage yourStaticArray]];
```

Knows in what class to look for the NSCode? Right now I'm getting the error above because it is searching for the NSCode in the wrong place.
In the class `PeopleData` there's nothing but properties.

Comment: I hope you want to store an array in NSUserDefaults??right..??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you archive or unarchive an object, at that time `initWithCoder` or `encodeWithCoder` is called.
Please implement [NSCoding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) in `PeopleData` class

For tutorial about `NSCoding`. [Here is the good tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1914/how-to-save-your-app-data-with-nscoding-and-nsfilemanager).

Comment: I have the NSCoding implemented in my code in another class. The fact that the compiler is searching for it in PeopleData, does it mean that I need NSCoding there too?

Comment: Every object that is put into the archive must conform to `NSCoding`.

Comment: @RobNapier That's the info I was missing. I thought that if an array is inside an array , it's enough if only the exterior is archived.